# Какие существуют способы инверсии массива в Java?

Tags: java, массивы

Какие существуют способы инверсии массива в Java?

Comment: ну, вот такой существует почти в любом языке (с поправкой на синтаксис): `for(int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)`
нужно вашу задачу конкретнее узнать, чтобы можно было ответить

Comment: @iksuy а зачем итерировать весь массив для переворачивания массива ?

Comment: @aleshka-batman, это к вопросу о задаче. Если нужен перевернутый массив, значит вероятно с ним с перевернутым что-то хотят делать. Но можно рассмотреть исходный массив, как уже перевернутый и просто обойти его с конца. Поскольку автор не уточнил, что ему нужно, а захотел узнать способы, мой комментарий вполне подходит под вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Самый нативный видать это c Commons.Lang

```
ArrayUtils.reverse(Object[] array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Бежим от начала до (length / 2) и меняем местами текущий с (последний - текущий)

Answer (score 1):

Есть вариант через Stream API:

```
public Integer[] sortArray(Integer[] array) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, array.length)
            .mapToObj(i -> array[array.length - i])
            .toArray(Integer[]::new);
}
```